# How do I open multiple forms on a single HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a single Bootstrap HTML page that is a repository for a large number of forms (quizzes). Currently I have the quizzes opening in a bootstrap modal via iFrame, but the lag on the initial load of the repository page is bad (too many calls to the server for the iFrames).

This is for work so the server is Oracle (no php), and the systems are still all XP using IE8.

The iFrames work but they lag the page. How do I go about opening multiple versions of this form without leaving the page?

Quizzes follow this format: http://techlaboratory.net/techlab/demos/SmartWizard2/

---

Based on the Ajax suggestion I tried to mimic the example I found but I must be missing something.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ajax test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function showUrlInDialog(url){
   var tag = $("<div></div>");
      $.ajax({
         url: url,
           success: function(data) {
              tag.html(data).dialog({modal: true}).dialog('open');
                }
                   });
                    } 

</script>
</head>

<body>

<a href="#" onclick="showUrlInDialog('../../quiz_all/match.html'); return false;">Match quiz</a> 


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would turn it into an Ajax UI where you fetch your quizzes through ajax calls and insert them into the DOM directly. This means you can get by with a single page application and no iframes

Comment: I have tried doing that with the remote option on the bootstrap modals but I am getting a conflict in code. The smartwizard must be conflicting with some bootstrap script. As I am not going to find the conflict (wasted a week already) should I look for an out of the box solution like prettyphoto who say they can do an ajax call or is this an easier solution.

Comment: Hard to say what the conflicts are, but one approach is to manage the ajax calls in regular JQuery

Comment: Am I looking at something like this? http://8raystech.com/2011/06/28/how-to-dynamic-content-in-a-jquery-ui-dialog-by-loading-a-url-via-ajax . I need an example to pick apart the code as I cannot write it myself.